# Вычисление квадранта, в котором находится точка двумерной координатной плоскости.

Tags: битовые-операции, c, геометрия

Здравствуйте, существует ли машинный способ определения квадранта, в котором находится точка с координатами x и y?

---

Наивное [решение](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-coordinate-point-xy-determine-quadrant/) делает простой перебор вариантов:

```
if (x > 0 && y > 0)

    printf("point (%d, %d) lies in the First quandrant\n");

else if (x < 0 && y > 0)

    printf("point (%d, %d) lies in the Second quandrant\n");

else if (x < 0 && y < 0)

    printf("point (%d, %d) lies in the Third quandrant\n");

else if (x > 0 && y < 0)

    printf("point (%d, %d) lies in the Fourth quandrant\n");

else if (x == 0 && y == 0)

    printf("point (%d, %d) lies at the origin\n");
```

---

Вот мой более общий вариант (внимание: в моём варианте точка 0,0 координатной плоскости находится на северо-западе и является наименьшей, отсюда и несколько другое распределение номеров квадрантов, но суть та же) для нахождения квадранта распределения точки point от данной точки centerPoint вариант (для пограничных случаев я намеренно помещаю точки, лежащие на границах квадрантов, в один из этих квадрантов):

```
if (point.x > centerPoint.x) {
    if (point.y > centerPoint.y) {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantFour;
    } else {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantOne;
    }
} else if (point.x < centerPoint.x) {
    if (point.y > centerPoint.y) {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantThree;
    } else {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantTwo;
    }
} else {
    if (point.y > centerPoint.y) {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantThree;
    } else if (point.y < centerPoint.y) {
        return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantTwo;
    }
}

return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantNone;
```

---

Под машинным способом я главным образом подразумеваю использование битовых операций: мы видим, что:

```
квадрант I)   x > 0, y > 0  => ++
квадрант II)  x < 0, y > 0  => -+
квадрант III) x < 0, y < 0  => --
квадрант IV)  x > 0, y < 0  => +-
```

...откуда, как подсказывает интуиция, можно было бы как-то схитрить, чтобы получилось:

```
+ ? + = 1
- ? + = 2
- ? - = 3
+ ? - = 4

или в контексте моей координатной системы с иным распределением квадрантов:

+ ? - = 1
- ? - = 2
- ? + = 3
+ ? + = 4
```

Вопрос в том, что может стоять за этим "?".

Буду рад любым советам. Интересуюсь этим вопросом больше для образования, хотя практика тоже обещает выиграть от этого, если такое решение возможно и существует.

Сам я также собираюсь посмотреть, как конкретно работают тангенсы и арктангенсы в С - возможно то, что они возвращают, мне тоже может как-то подойти.

Спасибо.

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ**

Только что нашёл решение на SO, только теперь нужно попытаться его, как следует, понять: [Optimizing quadrant selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313847/optimizing-quadrant-selection).

> The fastest way in C/C++ it would be
>   (((unsigned int)x >> 30) & 2) | ((unsigned int)y >> 31)
>   (30/31 or 62/63, depending on size of int). This will give the quadrants in order 0, 2, 3, 1.

И решение относительно данного центра:

> (((unsigned int)(x - center.x) >> 30) & 2) | ((unsigned int)(y-center.y) >> 31)

Буду признателен, если кто подскажет, что нужно изменить в этом решении, чтобы оно стало работать для точек x, y с типом double.

---

**Комментарий по поводу принятого ответа**

Оказалось, что всё-таки обычное решение с двойным if-else ветвлением работает быстрее, чем решение в принятом ответе (соотношение, которое я получаю достаточно стабильно: 160 к 180).

---

Вот окончательные версии, которые я сравнивал между собой (система координат инвертирована относительно оси **y** относительно декартовой):

**Версия с обычным ветвлением**:

```
static inline KPClusterDistributionQuadrant KPClusterDistributionQuadrantForPointInsideMapRectBranching(MKMapRect mapRect, MKMapPoint point) {
    MKMapPoint centerPoint = (MKMapPoint){
        mapRect.origin.x + mapRect.size.width / 2,
        mapRect.origin.y + mapRect.size.height / 2
    };

    if (point.x >= centerPoint.x) {
        if (point.y >= centerPoint.y) {
            return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantFour;
        } else {
            return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantOne;
        }
    } else {
        if (point.y >= centerPoint.y) {
            return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantThree;
        } else {
            return KPClusterDistributionQuadrantTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

**Вариант @paulgri**:

```
NS_INLINE int KPClusterDistributionQuadrantForPointInsideMapRect(MKMapRect mapRect, MKMapPoint point) {
    MKMapPoint centerPoint = (MKMapPoint){
        mapRect.origin.x + mapRect.size.width / 2,
        mapRect.origin.y + mapRect.size.height / 2
    };

    double dx = point.x - centerPoint.x;
    double dy = point.y - centerPoint.y;

    return ((*((long long *)&dy) >> 63) & 3) ^ ((*((long long *)&dx) >> 63) & 1);
}
```

**Решение со StackOverflow (адаптировано @avp для работы с double)**:

```
NS_INLINE int KPClusterDistributionQuadrantForPointInsideMapRect_avp(MKMapRect mapRect, MKMapPoint point) {
    MKMapPoint centerPoint = (MKMapPoint){
        mapRect.origin.x + mapRect.size.width / 2,
        mapRect.origin.y + mapRect.size.height / 2
    };

    double dx = point.x - centerPoint.x;
    double dy = point.y - centerPoint.y;

    return ((*((uint64_t *)&dx) >> 62) & 2) | (*((uint64_t *)&dy) >> 63);
}
```

**Еще одно решение, предложенное моим коллегой - оно более медленное, но все же рабочее, поэтому я добавляю его сюда для коллекции:**

```
uint32_t x = ...;
uint32_t y = ...;

char xsign = x >> 31 & 1;
char ysign = y >> 31 & 1;

int quadrant = 1 + (xsign ^ ysign) + 2 * ysign;
```

Comment: Я вижу, что в решении @paulgri в отличии от решения с SO мы имеем в общей сложности 5 битовых операций вместо 3, что даёт нам верный порядок квадрантов, но чуть меньшую скорость исполнения. Вроде бы разумно я это себе объясняю через 5 к 3, верно?

Кроме того, обобщая, можно сказать, что битовые операции будут выигрывать тогда, когда подсчёт будет происходить относительно точки 0, а не от данного центра, так как, когда мы используем битовые операции, нам нужно сначала подсчитать дельта-x и дельта-y, в if-подходе же сравнение делается напрямую просто в два if-а.

Comment: Осталось для полноты картины замерить вариант в лоб с atan2(y,x)

Comment: @avp, @paulgri. Ещё одна просьба про решение со SO: можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, что мы получаемб когда делаем __>> 62__? Я могу понять, что __>> 63__ получает знак, но вот с 62 что-то не могу догадаться. Спасибо.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: `>>62` тоже получает знак, но оставляет его не в 0-ой позиции, а в 1-ой. То есть для положительного числа получается 0, а для отрицательного — 2. Там наверняка должен ещё быть `&`, чтобы выключить остальные биты.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, там комментарии закончились.

Не знаю, чем объяснить. Даже результаты (наверное из-за разного алгоритма rand()) разные (но сумма 100000000) сходится.

--

Вообще, все эти микрооптимизации слишком зависят от особенностей компиляторов и моделей процессора, чтобы серьезно к ним относиться.

Comment: > Не знаю, чем объяснить. Даже результаты (наверное из-за разного алгоритма rand()) разные (но сумма 100000000) сходится.

Ничего, важно, что в общем случае, всё-таки следует на вооружение брать простое ветвление для случая со смещённым центром, и также хорошо, что топик получился очень насыщенный и поучительный (я очень много узнал!), надеюсь, не только для меня)) Как и всегда, спасибо Вам за участие!

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich: >>62 тоже получает знак, но оставляет его не в 0-ой позиции, а в 1-ой. То есть для положительного числа получается 0, а для отрицательного — 2. Там наверняка должен ещё быть &, чтобы выключить остальные биты.

@VladD, я удалил свой следующий комментарий с уточнением - я теперь всё понял и, наконец, разобрался с (x >> 62) & 2. Спасибо за разъяснение. И спасибо за участие!

Comment: Да. 

Я тоже думаю, что if-ами решать правильней (прежде всего -- понятнее, + явно переносимо, да еще и иногда просто быстрее).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если квадрант отыскивается относительно точки О(0,0), то можно обойтись битовыми операциями и манипулировать знаками чисел, зная, что сдвиг вправо является арифметическим (надеюсь, переменныне типа int?), например так (к размерам типов и пр. прошу не придираться, это набросок кода - только идея):

```
n = ((y>>31)&3 ^ (x>>31)&1) + 1;
```

Здесь +1 надо только для того, чтобы квадратны начинались с 1.

Если относительно некоторой точки (x0,y0), то достаточно вместо x и y поставить разности.

Как вариант - используйте тернарную операцию и обычные сравнения.

UPD: одновременно написали ))

Для типов с плавающей запятой битовые операции не применимы, используйте тернарную.

UPD2: обратите внимание, это не тот же вариант, в моем варианте квадратны нумеруются правильно, по порядку 1,2,3,4.

UPD3:
Если x и y переменные типа double, то можно указатели на них привести к указателям на целочисленный тип так, чтобы знаковые разряды мантиссы оказались на месте знаковых разрядов целого и дальше все по той же схеме. Только посмотреть надо, где они у double. Приведение указателей на примитивные типы - фактически фиктивная операция, время не тратится ни на какие преобразования.

Comment: @paulgri, спасибо за ответ. Про UPD2: да, я, конечно, заметил это.

А скажите, с точки зрения скорости не будет ли выгоднее при работе с double-координатами __кастить их в long и применять ваш способ__, вместо того, чтобы делать тернарные операции, как в моём способе в вопросе?

Comment: > А скажите, с точки зрения скорости не будет ли выгоднее...

Я сейчас всё проверю-измерю руками и посмотрю результаты, просто интересны теоретические рассуждения, которые могут стоять за/против в пользу тернарных операций против вашего решения.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, конечно с double вообще все дольше, но в данном случае действительно интересно, что быстрее: кастить+битовые или сравнивать+тернарная. Только эксперимент))

Comment: Если  x и y переменные типа double, то можно указатели на них привести к указателям на целочисленный тип так, чтобы знаковые разряды мантиссы оказались на месте знаковых разрядов целого и дальше все по той же схеме. Только посмотреть надо, где они у double.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, да, это интересный результат, надо учесть на будущее))

С такой задачей я не сталкивался, просто знание внутреннего представления данных и семантики операций. Вообще предпочитаю обходиться арифметикой, когда это возможно, вместо циклов и условий, формулы повыводить))

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich, да, это интересный результат, надо учесть на будущее))

Да, даже немного обидно, что не придётся воспользоваться изящным решением.

> С такой задачей я не сталкивался, просто знание внутреннего представления данных и семантики операций. Вообще предпочитаю обходиться арифметикой, когда это возможно, вместо циклов и условий, формулы повыводить))

Ага, спасибо. Можете что-то посоветовать для изучения в особом порядке по поводу этих самых представления данных и семантики?

Comment: Кажется, что кастить double не обязательно — он ведь тоже содержит бит знака:

    #include <assert.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    
    int quadrant(double x, double y) {
        assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(int64_t));
        int64_t _x = static_cast<int64_t>(x);
        int64_t _y = static_cast<int64_t>(y);
        return ((_y>>((sizeof(_y)<<3) - 1))&3 ^
                (_x>>((sizeof(_x)<<3) - 1)&1)) + 1;
    }

Comment: @Дож, всё верно, можно без каста! Я уже поправил это в своих решениях, а завтра обновлю здесь.

Comment: @Дож, здесь ведь static_cast - это то же, что и обычное приведение типа, будет потрачено время. Предлагаю reinterpret_cast, т.к. размеры одинаковы. Тогда избавимся еще и от лишних переменных, все свернется в одно выражение. Но это только C++.

@avp уже ответил про совпадение расположения знаковых разрядов (коммент к вопросу) и показал манипуляции с указателями - то что я подразумевал в UPD3. @avp, спасибо! Для несмещенного нуля опять можно свернуть в одно выражение, подставив *(long long *)&x вместо x и аналогично с y. Возможно, в итоге такой вариант окажется выигрышным.

Comment: Упс... Пропустил, вариант с указателями тоже протестили ))

Answer (score 6):

> Под машинным способом я главным образом подразумеваю использование битовых операций

Если Вы под этим завуалировали "как получить быстрое решение?", то мой вариант: слепите 4 бита сравнений координат с нулем и проверьте в `switch'е` все 16 комбинаций.

> Можете, пожалуйста, расписать подробно, так как я не уловил суть подхода?

```
int Quadrant( int x, int y ){
    unsigned a;
    //
    a    = ( x > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
    a   |= ( x < 0 ) ? 2 : 0;
    a   |= ( y > 0 ) ? 4 : 0;
    a   |= ( y < 0 ) ? 8 : 0;
    //
    switch( a ){
        case 5:     return 1;
        case 6:     return 2;
        case 9:     return 4;   // это не ошибка в расчетах квадранта,
        case 10:    return 3;   // это Декарт виноват :)
        default:    return -1;
    }
}
int Quadrant( int x, int y, int cx, int cy ){
    return Quadrant( x - cx, y - cy );
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы не рассчитывать признаки повторно.
 --
Здесь `4 + 4` операции сравнения, `3` - сложения, т.е. для получения результата требуется `от 8 до 11` операций. Еще можно попробовать заменить операции `4 + 3` на `1 - SIMD-сравнение`, получится где-то `от 2 до 5` операций, но скорее всего, это будет медленнее решения со `SO`, там, насколько я понял, всего `4` операции.
 --
Если вместо `switch`'а задействовать **бинарный поиск**, то можно сэкономить на одной операции.
 --
Можно, кстати, вообще убрать `switch` и использовать `"a"` в качестве результата, но, конечно, **номера** будут непопорядку, как и на `SO`.
 --
Зато быстро: грубо говоря - `за 1 SIMD-сравнение` или за `4 + 3` обычных (сравнения + сложения) ))
 --
Немного доработал алгоритм, чтобы получить **правильный порядок четвертей**. Это потребовало еще 1 дополнительную операцию:

```
int Quadrant( int x, int y ){
    unsigned a;
    //
    a    = ( x > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
    a   |= ( x < 0 ) ? 2 : 0;
    a   |= ( y > 0 ) ? 4 : 0;
    //a |= ( y < 0 ) ? 8 : 0;
    if( y < 0 ){
        a   ^= 3;   //  инверсия признаков в I и II полуплоскостях
        a   |= 8;
    }
    //
    switch( a ){
        case 5:     return 1;
        case 6:     return 2;
        case 9:     return 3;   //  здесь уже 
        case 10:    return 4;   //  все верно, по Декарту! :)
        default:    return -1;
    }
}
```

Если задействовать `SIMD`, то придется сначала выполнить `SIMD-сравнение` с `0` и за'xor'ить первые два юнита, если 4 юнит `не ноль`. Т.е. выходит **три операции** вместо одной из предыдущего варианта.

**Note**: при задействовании PCMPGTD (SSE2), такую скорость можно получить только в потоковом режиме, т.е. на наборе точек > 2 штук, т.к., насколько я знаю, нет в этой спецификации такой SIMD-операции, которая может применить к каждому юниту произвольную операцию сравнения (но не факт :), могли уже ввести, на более современном железе).

Тут, к примеру, для первого варианта алгоритма придется в первом SIMD-векторе вычислить { x1 > 0, x2 > 0, y1 > 0, y2 > 0 }, а на втором - { 0 > x1, 0 > x2, 0 > y1, 0 > y2 }. Комбинация этих двух векторов и дает результат для двух точек.

**Выходит, 2 операции на 2 точки**, а не 1 на 1. Для второго алгоритма все аналогично: 6 операций на 2 точки.
 --
Немного доработал алгоритм, чтобы получить еще и **правильный номер четвертей**:

```
int Quadrant( int x, int y ){
    int a, b;
    //
    a    = ( x > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
    a   |= ( x < 0 ) ? 2 : 0;
    b    = ( y > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
    if( y < 0 ){
        a   ^= 3;
        b   |= 2;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

Здесь 4 сравнения 3 сложения 1 - xor, т.е. 8 простых операций, без проверки на равенство 0: если `a` или `b` равны 0, то точка лежит на базисе, поэтому результат будет неверным.

Может показаться, что `SSE` здесь так же может ускорить расчет: `4 сравнения и 2 сложения` заменяются на `1 SIMD-сравнение`, оставляя `1 сложение` и `1 xor`, но увы - только если в `SSE` будет введена команда 4-битного сложения, где **бит соответствует одному юниту вектора**, а такого в спецификации я не наблюдал.

Подвожу свои итоги:

1. Самая быстрая реализация **первого** алгоритма дает результат **за одну операцию**, что условно в 3 раза быстрее, чем на `SO`. Размер результата **128 бит**. Если надо меньше, то можно его сжать до **32 бит**, если задействовать еще `1-2 операции упаковки` (сейчас точное число операций упаковки не скажу, надо смотреть документацию, есть ли вариант упаковки из 32-битного сразу в 8-битный юнит).
2. Самая быстрая реализация **второго** алгоритма дает результат **за три операции**, что на 1 условную операцию меньше, чем на `SO`. Кроме того, этот алгоритм дает **правильный топологический порядок четвертей**, что позволяет сравнивать и упорядочивать точки по квадрантам, минуя дополнительные трансформации, т.е. еще быстрее.
3. При использовании типа `float`, оба алгоритма сохраняют скорости.
4. При использовании типа `double` или `long long`, число операций для обоих алгоритмов увеличивается на `1` (на `SSE <= 4`).
5. На `SSE5`, при использовании типа `double` или `long long`, оба алгоритма сохраняют скорости.

**Для справки**: скорость **PCMPEQD/PCMPEQW/PCMPEQB** (32/16/8-битное SIMD-сравнение двух векторов) составляет в среднем от 4 до 6 нс. (<10тыс. итераций), от 25 до 48 нс. (<10млн. итераций). на 1Ггц (тестировал в конце прошлого года на своем кластере: 8x E5450 @ 3.0GHz, SSE4.1). Т.е., в сравнении с 0 (для PCMPGTD), могу предположить скорость не менее указанной, а то и выше, ибо в этом случае производится чтение только одного вектора.

---

> но могли бы Вы чётко расписать/пометить/представить, какова именно "Самая быстрая реализация первого алгоритма", которая "дает результат за одну операцию"

Я и не писал быстрые варианты, я написал 3 общих варианта без векторизации. Векторизация может быть реализована по разному, смотрите примечание Note. К примеру, реализацию первого алгоритма для двух точек может быть такой (MSVS):

```
static const __m128i zero = _mm_set_epi32( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
__m128i pair = _mm_set_epi32( y2, y1, x2, x1 );
__m128i p1 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( pair, zero );
__m128i p2 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( zero, pair );
```

Результат для первой точки находится в векторе

```
{ p2.m128i_i32[2], p2.m128i_i32[0], p1.m128i_i32[2], p1.m128i_i32[0] },
```

а для второй, соответственно - в векторе

```
{ p2.m128i_i32[3], p2.m128i_i32[1], p1.m128i_i32[3], p1.m128i_i32[1] },
```

Как Вы их дальше будете использовать, зависит от Вашего потокового алгоритма: сохраните результаты в дополнительном векторе, или определите четверть сразу - дальнейшая скорость зависит от Вашей реализации.

> Что ж, тогда выходит, что Вы меня до смерти запугали разными очень низкоуровневыми и совершенно непонятными мне вещами, но при этом не предлагаете ни одного решения, которое стоило бы сравнить с уже имеющимися другими решениями

Ну что ж, сочувствую. Понимаю, что ответ скорее другого уровня. Тем не менее, пример я Вам дал, сожалею, если Вы не понимаете как его можно использовать.
 --
Если хотите просто измерить скорость, разделите исходную выборку точек по парам и вычислите для каждой эти три операции. На самом деле, ничего сложного, Вам просто нужно поставить его в те же условия, что и остальные алгоритмы, которые Вы тестируете.
 --
Кстати, было бы хорошо, если бы Вы старались использовать в своих несомненно весомых оценках русскую терминологию. Особенно, если Вы хотите, чтобы я мог Вам чем-то помочь.

> Ну смотрите, вот прототип static inline int quadrant(double x, double y, double centerX, double centerY);

[[@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich)](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich), Еще раз Вам повторяю **Note**:

> при задействовании PCMPGTD (SSE2), такую скорость можно получить только в потоковом режиме, т.е. **на наборе точек > 2 штук**

а Вы мне предлагаете 1 точку.

> показать работу с потоком, главное, чтобы решение было законченным и работало

Ждите, когда я найду для этого время, либо программиста, который прочитает мои инструкции и реализует в своем решении. Но Вы можете просто рассчитать, сколько времени работают остальные. ))

---

**Реализация для обоих алгоритмов (MSVS):**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <vector>
//
static const __m128i zero   = _mm_set_epi32( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
static const __m128i xor    = _mm_set_epi32( 0, 0, -1, -1 );
//
inline void Quadrant1( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, __m128i*p1, __m128i*p2 ){
    __m128i pair    = _mm_set_epi32( y2, x2, y1, x1 );
    __m128i gz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( pair, zero );
    __m128i lz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( zero, pair );
    *p1             = _mm_unpacklo_epi32( gz, lz );
    *p2             = _mm_unpackhi_epi32( gz, lz );
}
//
inline void Quadrant2( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, __m128i*p1, __m128i*p2 ){
    __m128i pair    = _mm_set_epi32( y2, x2, y1, x1 );
    __m128i gz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( pair, zero );
    __m128i lz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( zero, pair );
    *p1             = _mm_unpacklo_epi32( gz, lz );
    *p2             = _mm_unpackhi_epi32( gz, lz );
    //
    if( lz.m128i_i32[1] ){
        *p1 = _mm_xor_si128( *p1, xor );
    }
    if( lz.m128i_i32[3] ){
        *p2 = _mm_xor_si128( *p2, xor );
    }
}
//
int _tmain( int argc, LPCTSTR argv[] ){
    static const DWORD Measure  = 5000;
    //
    std::vector< POINT >Points;
    std::vector< __m128i >Q;
    ULONGLONG Start, T1, T2;
    DWORD_PTR Mask;
    double ms;
    SIZE_T ic, p1, p2, Count;
    //
    if( ( argc < 2 ) || ( 1 != _stscanf_s( argv[1], TEXT("%Iu"), &Count ) ) ){
        return 0;
    }
    _tprintf( TEXT("count=%Iu\r\n" ), Count );
    Mask    = ::SetThreadAffinityMask( ::GetCurrentThread(), 1 );
    _tprintf( TEXT("measure...\r\n" ) );
    Start   = __rdtsc();
    Sleep( Measure );
    ms      = double( __rdtsc() - Start ) / Measure;
    _tprintf( TEXT("Freq=%lf GHz\r\n" ), ms / 1000000 );
    //
    srand( (unsigned)time( nullptr ) );
    Points.resize( Count );
    Q.resize( Count );
    _tprintf( TEXT("filling...\r\n" ) );
    for( ic = Count ; ic-- ; ){
        Points[ic].x    = rand();
        Points[ic].y    = rand();
    }
    _tprintf( TEXT("calc...\r\n" ) );
    Start   = __rdtsc();
    for( p1 = 0, p2 = 1, ic = Count / 2 ; ic-- ; ++p1, ++p2 ){
        Quadrant1( Points[p1].x, Points[p1].y, Points[p2].x, Points[p2].y, &Q[p1], &Q[p2] );
    }
    T1      = __rdtsc() - Start;
    Start   = __rdtsc();
    for( p1 = 0, p2 = 1, ic = Count / 2 ; ic-- ; ++p1, ++p2 ){
        Quadrant2( Points[p1].x, Points[p1].y, Points[p2].x, Points[p2].y, &Q[p1], &Q[p2] );
    }
    T2      = __rdtsc() - Start;
    _tprintf(
        TEXT("SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): %lf/%lf ms.\r\n"), T1 / ms, T1 / 1000000.0
    );
    _tprintf(
        TEXT("SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): %lf/%lf ms.\r\n"), T2 / ms, T2 / 1000000.0
    );
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask( ::GetCurrentThread(), Mask );
    return 0;
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
count=100000000
measure...
Freq=3.002832 GHz
filling...
calc...
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 534.183610/1604.063475 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 596.293807/1790.569944 ms.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Это расчеты на одном ядре. Первое значение - время, потраченное на расчет на частоте ~3GHz, второй - на условном 1GHz. Запускал много раз, расхождение в среднем не более 10мс. "Прогрев" ядра в начале 5 сек. Число точек то же самое, что и у [[[[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp): 100млн. ОЗУ достаточно медленное (8x 1GB PC2-5300), так что скорость на таком количестве точек еще может увеличиться, если запустить на быстрой памяти: каждый квадрант записывается в массив.

**DASM Quadrant1 (контекст):**

```
mov         dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],eax  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],ecx  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+34h],edx  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],r8d  
movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsp+30h]  
movdqa      xmm2,xmm0  
pcmpgtd     xmm2,xmm4  
movdqa      xmm1,xmm4  
pcmpgtd     xmm1,xmm0  
movdqa      xmm0,xmm2  
punpckldq   xmm0,xmm1  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r11],xmm0  
add         r11,10h  
punpckhdq   xmm2,xmm1  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r11],xmm2
```

**DASM Quadrant2 (контекст):**

```
mov         dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],ecx  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],edx  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+34h],eax  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],r8d  
movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsp+30h]  
movdqa      xmm2,xmm0  
pcmpgtd     xmm2,xmm4  
movdqa      xmm1,xmm4  
pcmpgtd     xmm1,xmm0  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [Points],xmm1  
movdqa      xmm0,xmm2  
punpckldq   xmm0,xmm1  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r9],xmm0  
punpckhdq   xmm2,xmm1  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r9+10h],xmm2  
cmp         dword ptr [rsp+44h],0  
je          wmain+2DBh (13FA7133Bh)  
movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [r9]  
pxor        xmm0,xmm3  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r9],xmm0  
cmp         dword ptr [rsp+4Ch],0  
je          wmain+2F2h (13FA71352h)  
movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [r9+10h]  
pxor        xmm0,xmm3  
movdqa      xmmword ptr [r9+10h],xmm0
```

---

Для произвольного центра результат такой:

```
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 559.389193/1678.360437 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 666.485334/1999.685781 ms.
```

Для произвольного центра, который учитывается через SIMD(PSUBD) результат такой:

```
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 553.127711/1661.376060 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 614.841356/1846.739349 ms.
```

На самом деле, быстрее всего расчет с произвольным центром будет в гомогенном потоке инструкций, т.е. предварительным циклом. Но в таком случае, эта "добавка" к расчетам будет ощущаться на уровне той же стартовой погрешности ))
 --
То же самое касается и `_mm_xor_si128`, который `xor'ит` квадрант во второй версии алгоритма. Т.е. в конечном счете, оба алгоритма могут работать примерно на одной скорости, если их грамотно специализировать под задачу. Собственно xor вообще можно вызвать обычный, `64-битный` (на `x64`).
 --
Ну и учтите, что я вызываю еще **две лишних команды** для первой версии (`punpckhdq/punpckldq`). Это нужно только для того, чтобы разделить результаты и записать их в память. Я мог бы просто записать в память пары квадрантов, это будет еще быстрее.
 --
Основное время съедает, конечно, работа с памятью.

---

Немного доработал реализацию, чтобы **упаковать 128-битные квадранты в 32-битные слова**:

```
static const __m128i shfl   = _mm_set_epi8(
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12, 8, 4, 0
);
...
inline void Quadrant1( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, const __m128i&c, int*q1, int*q2 ){
    __m128i pair    = _mm_sub_epi32( _mm_set_epi32( y2, x2, y1, x1 ), c );
    __m128i gz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( pair, zero );
    __m128i lz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( zero, pair );
    __m128i p1      = _mm_unpacklo_epi32( gz, lz );
    __m128i p2      = _mm_unpackhi_epi32( gz, lz );
    *q1             = _mm_shuffle_epi8( p1, shfl ).m128i_i32[0];
    *q2             = _mm_shuffle_epi8( p2, shfl ).m128i_i32[0];
}
//
inline void Quadrant2( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, const __m128i&c, int*q1, int*q2 ){
    __m128i pair    = _mm_sub_epi32( _mm_set_epi32( y2, x2, y1, x1 ), c );
    __m128i gz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( pair, zero );
    __m128i lz      = _mm_cmpgt_epi32( zero, pair );
    __m128i p1      = _mm_unpacklo_epi32( gz, lz );
    __m128i p2      = _mm_unpackhi_epi32( gz, lz );
    //
    if( lz.m128i_i32[1] ){
        p1  = _mm_xor_si128( p1, xor );
    }
    if( lz.m128i_i32[3] ){
        p2  = _mm_xor_si128( p2, xor );
    }
    *q1             = _mm_shuffle_epi8( p1, shfl ).m128i_i32[0];
    *q2             = _mm_shuffle_epi8( p2, shfl ).m128i_i32[0];
}
```

На этом этапе каждый квадрант 4-битный, с размером бита в 1 байт, поэтому, если нужен `switch`, то он должен быть уже таким для первого варианта:

```
switch( a ){
    case 0x00ff00ff:    return 1;
    case 0x00ffff00:    return 2;
    case 0xff0000ff:    return 4;
    case 0xff00ff00:    return 3;
    default:        return -1;
}
```

и для второго:

```
switch( a ){
    case 0x00ff00ff:    return 1;
    case 0x00ffff00:    return 2;
    case 0xff0000ff:    return 3;
    case 0xff00ff00:    return 4;
    default:        return -1;
}
```

Скорость этого варианта:

```
count=100000000
measure...
Freq=3.002314 GHz
filling...
calc...
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 557.680927/1674.333081 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 648.186217/1946.058354 ms.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Т.е., как ни крути, а скорость обоих моих вариантов больше по крайней мере **в три раза**.

Полностью нагрузил узел, на 500 млн., вышел такой результат:

```
count=500000000
measure...
Freq=3.002184 GHz
filling...
calc...
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 2731.684208/8201.019582 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 3532.774079/10606.039056 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000005/0.000016 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000007/0.000021 ms.
SIMD speed Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 183037262.683/60968029.036 q./sec.
SIMD speed Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 141531835.549/47142952.931 q./sec.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

3 секунды все таки более стабильный результат, можно точнее посчитать скорость: `140/47-180/60` млн. квадрантов в секунду (Freq/1GHz).

---

Изменил алгоритм генерации координат, как у [[[[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp):

```
rand() - INT_MAX / 2
```

Запретил запись в вектор `Q` (удалилил его, но прописал `volatile int*q1, volatile int*q2` в параметрах к функциям `Quadrant` ). Увеличил число координат до `700 млн`. Выиграл `1нс.` на втором алгоритме, т.е. они сблизились:

```
count=700000000
measure...
Freq=3.000889 GHz
filling...
calc...
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 3779.277685/11341.192149 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 4058.144274/12178.039779 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000005/0.000016 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000006/0.000017 ms.
SIMD speed Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 185220578.727715/61721906.374871 q./ms.
SIMD speed Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 172492635.220518/57480515.148841 q./ms.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Для [[[[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), после анализа его исходников я доработал реализацию с 2 добавлениями:

1. Готовлю сразу SIMD-векторы, для подачи в Quadrant
2. Немного разворачиваю циклы

**Исходник реализации:** http://pastebin.com/u63d8abp

**Вывод:**

```
count=100000000
measure...
Freq=3.000481 GHz
fill...
calc...
SIMD time Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 321.122363/963.521667 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 314.661862/944.137053 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 444.856547/1334.783781 ms.
SIMD avg. time Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 0.000003/0.000010 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000003/0.000009 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000004/0.000013 ms.
SIMD speed Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 311407773.002369/103785938.007349 p./s.
SIMD speed Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 317801462.834867/105916826.039450 q./s.
SIMD speed Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 224791566.118078/74918500.976302 q./s.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

А теперь **делаем ошибку**: `p += Exp` меняем на `++p`. Т.е. объем вычислений не меняем, просто уменьшаем число обращений к `ОЗУ`.

**Вывод:**

```
count=100000000
measure...
Freq=3.001383 GHz
fill...
calc...
SIMD time Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 26.564881/79.731387 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 133.211034/399.817350 ms.
SIMD time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 195.823826/587.742327 ms.
SIMD avg. time Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 0.000000/0.000001 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000001/0.000004 ms.
SIMD avg. time Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 0.000002/0.000006 ms.
SIMD speed Recenter (Freq/1GHz): 3764368388.323660/1254211217.973670 p./s.
SIMD speed Quadrant1 (Freq/1GHz): 750688565.116046/250114208.400411 q./s.
SIMD speed Quadrant2 (Freq/1GHz): 510663089.915592/170142586.991187 q./s.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Теперь, надеюсь, понятно, какую роль в вычислениях играет память и частота.

Comment: @mega: мегакруто, да.

Comment: @mega, масштаб исследования впечатляет ))

Comment: Спасибо, было интересно!

Comment: @mega, сделал с предвычислением (положил все в http://pastebin.com/zgwQnnHL).

Со сдвигами получилось **очень быстро** (порядка 140 мсек., а с if-ми прядка 500).

Краем глаза посмотрел ассемблер, со сдвигами в потоке сплошные xmm.

--

Правда, у меня памяти мало, поэтому выделял по 10000000 double на `x[]` и `y[]`, а результат (номера квадрантов) в `char q[10000000]`, ну и зациклил 10-ю итерациями. (все равно кэш у меня 6 мегов).

Comment: @mega, там (к своему ответу) у меня комменты кончились. 

Вечерком я положу ассемблерный код куда-нибудь на pastebin.

А вообще я незамысловато компилировал `gcc tttx.c -std=gnu99 -O3`, соответственно -- `gcc tttx.c -std=gnu99 -O3 -S` сделает tttx.s с ассемблером.

Comment: @mega, я положил ассемблерный код в http://pastebin.com/kF4NgUkD

Не совсем понял, что Вы имели в виду, говоря о привязки к частотам.

Если пересчитать с моих 3.30 на 1Ггц, то должно быть


    (* 140 3.3)
    462.0
    (* 560 3.3)
    1848.0

в миллисекундах для 100 млн. точек

Comment: Еще раз расширил ответ!

Answer (score 5):

[[@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich)](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich), решение SO (только для несдвинутого нуля) для double

```
  for (double a = 1; a > -2; a -= 2) 
    for (double b = 1; b > -2; b -= 2) {
      uint64_t *pa = (void *)&a, *pb = (void *)&b;
      int qn = ((*pa >> 62) & 2) | (*pb >> 63);
      printf("[%f , %f] qn = %d\n", a, b, qn);
    }
```

основано на том, что знак double хранится в старшем разряде long long.

--

Кстати, странно, что оно оказалось медленнее вложенных if-ов. Попробуйте один-в-один в "заинлайненном варианте" (вообще без функций, структур и т.п.).

**UPDATE**

Я измерил время вот так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  double a = 10, b = -10;
  uint64_t *pa = (void *)&a, *pb = (void *)&b;

  int n = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "10000000");
  int qn, cnt[4] = {0};
  srand(0);
  long long start = mtime();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    b = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    qn = ((*pa >> 62) & 2) | (*pb >> 63);
    cnt[qn]++;
  }
  printf ("shift: %lld (msec) n: %d [%d %d %d %d]\n",
          mtime() - start, n, cnt[0], cnt[1], cnt[2], cnt[3]);

  memset(cnt, 0, sizeof(cnt));
  srand(0);
  start = mtime();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    b = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    if ( a < 0) 
      if (b < 0)
        qn = 3;
      else
        qn = 2;
    else
      if (b < 0)
        qn = 1;
      else
        qn = 0;
    cnt[qn]++;
  }
  printf ("if: %lld (msec) n: %d [%d %d %d %d]\n",
          mtime() - start, n, cnt[0], cnt[1], cnt[2], cnt[3]);

}

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc tttx.c -std=gnu99 -O3
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 1874 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
if: 2409 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 1838 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
if: 2285 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 1848 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
if: 2310 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003913 24997412 24993577 25005098]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Получил, что if-ами медленнее.

**UPDATE-2**

Добавил `double dx, dy` и перемерил

```
  ....
  double dx = 1000, dy = 2000;
  ....
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    b = rand() - INT_MAX / 2;
    a += dx; b += dy;  // вот это добавил
    qn = ((*pa >> 62) & 2) | (*pb >> 63);
    cnt[qn]++;
  }
  ......
    if ( a < -dx)   // вот так изменил тут
      if (b < -dy)
    ...
      if (b < -dy)
```

а вот результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 2077 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
if: 2487 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 1962 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
if: 2286 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 100000000
shift: 2006 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
if: 2307 (msec) n: 100000000 [25003993 24997380 24993591 25005036]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

все равно показывает, что if-ами медленнее.

Comment: @avp, я снова преобразовал ваш скромный комментарий в ответ, так как он того очень заслуживает! Спасибо!

Comment: @avp: медленнее `if`'ов может оказаться потому, что компилятор не смог отоптимизировать цикл по double.

PS: А не нужно ли случайно всё же `(*pa >> 62) & 2`?

Comment: @VladD, @Stanislaw Pankevich, безусловно, надо `& 2`. 

Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Замерил время у себя. Результат в **UPDATE** ответа (if-ами медленнее).

Comment: @avp, важное уточнение: мой тест работает с ненулевым центром! Как я и говорил, у вас скорее всего битовый вариант получается быстрее из-за того, что битовый вариант не считает разности (дельта-х и дельта-у). 

Попробуйте, пожалуйста, учесть это, так как хочется выяснить решение для общего вида с не нулевым, а произвольным центром!

Comment: Сделал измерения со смещениями dx, dy. Результат в **UPDATE-2** (по сути не изменился).

@Stanislaw Pankevich, а у Вас какой компилятор (и CPU)?

Comment: Вот:

    Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
    Thread model: posix

    Core i5 1,8 Ghz

Такой информации достаточно?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте просто мой тест у себя запустить. Что получается?

Comment: Вот, пожалуйста:

shift: 1793 (msec) n: 100000000 [24997633 25004457 24993650 25004260]
if: 1758 (msec) n: 100000000 [24997633 25004457 24993650 25004260]

Comment: >Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

>Core i5 1,8 Ghz

>avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz


Пардон, @Stanislaw Pankevich, а мне, собственно интересно только одно: как Вы  на своем `1,8 Ghz` обогнали @avp на `3.30GHz`?

Comment: @avp, Вы не отделили стадию генерации координат от самих расчетов квадрантов. Думаю, тут Вы и потеряли время. Попробуйте заполнить массив координат до самой стадии расчетов.

Comment: >сделал с предвычислением (положил все в http://pastebin.com/zgwQnnHL ) Со сдвигами получилось очень быстро (порядка 140 мсек., а с if-ми прядка 500)

Отлично! Я конечно предполагал ускорение примерно на порядок, но не такое. Особенно подозрительны скорости ifов.

>Краем глаза посмотрел ассемблер, со сдвигами в потоке - сплошные xmm

А вот это уже многое объясняет. Можно посмотреть ассемблерные вырезки контекста? И я бы еще хотел взглянуть на аналогичную статистику, привязанную к частотам, как в моем примере.

>А вообще я незамысловато компилировал

Выходит, gcc оптимизирует с SSE по умолчани

Comment: >я положил ассемблерный код в http://pastebin.com/kF4NgUkD

Посмотрел код, да, действительно, все вычисления там на SSE. Команды вроде 32-битные, т.е. в SIMD используется так же пара координат, как и у меня. Только вот объем расчетов намного больше. Если смотреть на L14, видно, что **во первых** данные не готовятся перед каждой итерацией: видимо, они сразу хранятся выровненными и просто интерпретируются как SIMD-векторы, **во вторых** используется параллельный логический сдвиг вправо PSRLQ. В третьих: вижу по крайней мере 8 сдвигов на 62 в итерации, т.е. цикл частично развернут, видимо.

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация с If'ами, смотрите на L45: я, конечно не делал поиск с пристрастием, но могу предположить, что это именно он. Для меня тут катализатор - `PCMPGT` - параллельное сравнение двух SIMD векторов.

Comment: Чтобы исключить влияние `Turbo Boost'а`, при наличии.  
 --  
В Вашем случае, конечно будет логичнее показать скорости без `SSE`, но, насколько я понял, `gcc` не может отключить поддержку `SSE` полностью. Интересно, как его код работает на машинах без `SSE` (без `128битных` векторов, в частности), или таких уже не существует?

Answer (score 3):

У меня везде закончились комментарии, поэтому задам свой последний вопрос по поводу обоих битовых вариантов здесь в виде ответа:

**вариант [[@paulgri](/users/14613/paulgri)](/users/14613/paulgri)**:

```
double dx = point.x - center.x;
double dy = point.y - center.y;

return ((*((long long *)&dy) >> 63) & 3) ^ ((*((long long *)&dx) >> 63) & 1);
```

вариант **SO и [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)**:

```
double dx = point.x - center.x;
double dy = point.y - center.y;

return ((*((uint64_t *)&dx) >> 62) & 2) | (*((uint64_t *)&dy) >> 63);
```

Что я не понимаю, так это то, почему, хотя мы и делаем очень похожие сдвиги в обоих случаях, в первом варианте **каст происходит в long long *, а потом берётся* pdx и *pdy**, а во втором варианте **каст происходит в uint64t *, а потом тоже берётся* pdx и *pdy**? Оба варианта перестают работать, если я заменяю в первом `long long *` на `uint64t *` и наоборот: во втором заменяю `uint64t *` на `long long *`. Прошу прокомментировать эту разницу использования промежуточного указателя на знаковый 64-битный тип в одном варианте и использования промежуточного указателя на беззнаковый 64-битный тип в другом варианте. Спасибо.

**P.S.** ХэшКод съедает своей разметкой символы _ и *, но смысл вроде всё равно ясен!

Comment: Все дело в том, что сдвиг вправо является арифметическим. В моем случае важно, что long long - знаковый тип и при сдвиге ВСЕ разряды заполняются исходным значением знакового разряда. Во втором случае важен беззнаковый тип, чтобы заполнение слева происходило нулями.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: парсер не съедает `*` и `_` внутри обратных кавычек.

1. В варианте №1 `*pdy >> 63` сдвиг знаковый. Поэтому `(*pdy >> 63)` размножает знаковый бит на все биты результата. `(*pdy >> 63)` ограничивает его до **двух** младших битов. XOR с `(*pdx >> 63) & 1` меняет только младший бит, если `dy` был отрицательным.

2. В этом коде всё приводится к беззнаковым числам, при сдвиге старший бит оригинала **не** размножается. Здесь первый сдвиг не на 63, а на 62, что приводит старший бит `dx` в позицию 1, а `(*pdy >> 63)` приводит старший бит `dy` в позицию 0.

Comment: @paulgri, спасибо! Я как раз искал про разницу правого сдвига для беззнаковых типов и всё никак не мог найти толкового ответа - то есть это __точно, что при сдвигах вправо переменной беззнакового типа заполнение (padding) всегда происходит нулями__?

Comment: В моей формуле при отрицательном значении dy его единичное значение знакового разряда (который после сдвига в разрядах 0 и 1, остальные отсекаются &3) инвертирует знаковый разряд dx (который теперь в разряде 0), чем и достигается правильный порядок квадрантов.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: для беззнакового типа сдвиг вправо заполняет результат нулями, для знакового — размножает знаковый бит.

    abcdefgh  (беззнаковое)         abcdefgh  (знаковое)
                           сдвиг
    000abcde                        aaaabcde

Comment: @paulgri, @VladD, большое спасибо! Всё стало на свои места.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, да, для беззнаковых - нулями, для знаковых - значением знакового разряда.

Comment: P.S. А я после * ставлю пробел, хоть и не всегда к месту, но прокатывает ))

P.P.S. Еще маленькая ручная оптимизация: можно в последнем варианте здесь избавиться от двух переменных и их инициализации - это время и место. Вместо pdx записать *(long long *)&dx и аналогично для dy. И тут тоже лимит комментариев, кстати.

Comment: > P.P.S. Еще маленькая ручная оптимизация: можно в последнем варианте здесь избавиться от двух переменных и их инициализации - это время и место. Вместо pdx записать (long long )&dx и аналогично для dy. И тут тоже лимит комментариев, кстати.

Спасибо, сделаю)) Хочется упаковать этот топик по полной))

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что можно это сделать и в первом варианте?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: угу. В C++ для такого существует [`reinterpret_cast<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), кстати.

Answer (score 1):

Авторское "наивное решение" вообще не даёт результата для точек, лежащих на осях (кроме центральной точки). С учётом этого обстоятельства и требуемой нечувствительности к типу исходных данных базовое решение может выглядеть так:

```
function quadrant($x,$y) { 
    return ($x==0 || $y==0) ? 0 : ($x>0 ? ($y>0?1:4) : ($y>0?2:3));
} 
printf("x = %5.2f &emsp; y= %5.2f &emsp; quadrant= %d<br>", $x= 0,    $y= 0,    quadrant($x,$y));
printf("x = %5.2f &emsp; y= %5.2f &emsp; quadrant= %d<br>", $x= 1e-1, $y= 1e-1, quadrant($x,$y));
printf("x = %5.2f &emsp; y= %5.2f &emsp; quadrant= %d<br>", $x=-1e-1, $y= 1e-1, quadrant($x,$y));
printf("x = %5.2f &emsp; y= %5.2f &emsp; quadrant= %d<br>", $x=-1e-1, $y=-1e-1, quadrant($x,$y));
printf("x = %5.2f &emsp; y= %5.2f &emsp; quadrant= %d<br>", $x= 1e-1, $y=-1e-1, quadrant($x,$y));
```

Результаты:

```
x = 0.00   y= 0.00   quadrant= 0
x = 0.10   y= 0.10   quadrant= 1
x = -0.10   y= 0.10   quadrant= 2
x = -0.10   y= -0.10   quadrant= 3
x = 0.10   y= -0.10   quadrant= 4
```