# Сравнение Float vs Double

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

Существует множество противоречивой информации по поводу производительности `float` и `double` на платформе `x86-64`. Хотелось бы разобраться в этом вопросе.

Так как на этот вопрос сложно дать однозначный ответ и как правило используют вещественные с двойной точностью, предлагаю рассмотреть ситуации, в которых действительно стоит использовать именно `float` вместо `double`

Comment: Я добавил больше языков, так будет веселее :) А если серьёзно, то плясать нужно от C++, но так больше людей подтянется, а double и float везде одинаков.

Comment: Кажется, у Страуструпа встречается такая рекомендация по выбору между этими двумя типами: перед выбором проконсультируйтесь с подкованным специалистом, либо разберитесь в этом вопросе в деталях, либо используйте double и надейтесь на лучшее. Поэтому присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Comment: Какой ответ хотите услышать? Типа *"float быстрее double на X%"*? Никто вам такого не скажет, потому что всё сильно зависит от сценария. Если просто складывать числа, разницы не будет никакой. Если же перегонять огромные матрицы через память, то программа с double может оказаться в 2 раза медленнее, просто потому, что double занимает в 2 раза больше памяти. Возьмите конкретный сценарий, который вас интересует, возьмите [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) и померьте! А потом нам расскажете...

Comment: @apangin цель этого вопроса как раз рассмотреть распространенные ситуации, когда стоит применять тот или иной тип данных. //Вопрос я задавал не для себя, а по причине разгоревшегося холивара в комментах одного вопроса.

Comment: Вот, ровно поэтому (из-за холиваров) подобные вопросы на "большом" StackOverflow закрывают как *too broad* или *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: Ваш исправленный вопрос не имеет ничего общего с тем «холиваром», о котором Вы говорите. Помните с чего всё началось? «Надо использовать double!» — только вот с какого перепугу его нужно использовать по умолчанию никто так и не смог объяснить. Текущий же вопрос стоит так, как будто float это какой-то второсортный тип, чьё использование должно быть обосновано, с чего бы вдруг?

Comment: @ixSci де-факто double используют по умолчанию, а float практически не используется. Именно по этмому в рамках данного вопроса нужно продемонстрировать задачи где от float реальная польза. От себя, на счет double. Ряд основных мат. операций ориентированны как раз на double, и в обычных математических операциях(умножение\деление) float выигрывает незначительно, менее 1%. А если использовать встроенные операции, которые заточены под double, то вероятно будет даже преимущество за double, но пока я еще это не проверял.

Comment: Откуда Вы взяло это «де факто»? Нет, не используется double по умолчанию

Comment: @ixSci де факто, по тому, что var val = 0.0 <=> double val = 0.0

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, ну это ведь не показатель. Добавьте туда f - `0.0f` и число становится float. float используется в огромном количестве библиотек, который задумываются о производительности, чтобы называть double стандартом

Comment: Я в курсе, что если добавить `f`, то получится `float`, только большинство разработчиков не заморачиваются, т.к. в энтерпрайзе байтоэкономика не поощряется, а большинство математических операций ограничивается стандартными операциями и функциями, которые `double`-ориентированы. В моей практике не мало действительно крупных проектов, но сколько бы я не пытался, я не смог припомнить, что бы пригодились `float`. Точность всегда была важнее.

Comment: Т.е. 7-8 знаков точности float вам было недостаточно? Это что за энтерпрайз такой?

Comment: @ixSci система мониторинга, которая должна была уметь работать с любыми датчиками, с поддержкой различных стратегий. Вот вы можете дать гарантию, что нету датчиков, для которых не достаточно флоата? Лично я нет. И опять же, базовые операции double ориентированы, а разницы на простых операциях между флоатом и даблом нету. Так что использование флоатов не имеет большого смысла. Я вот вижу, вы любите использовать `float`ы, наверняка у вас есть практические примеры, которые наглядно демонстрирую целессообразность использование этого типа. Покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, безусловно, если есть потенциальная нужда использовать double, то нужно его использовать. Я не любитель `float`, я просто не люблю, когда выдают желаемое за действительное. У меня в практике был только один проект, который использовала вычисления с плавающей запятой массово — так вот там использовался float и doublе, этот выбор делал не я и не могу сказать, насколько он обоснован.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `float`, как и ожидалось, быстрее `double`, поэтому, если вы работаете с большими объемами данных и вам хватает точности `float`, то вы выбираете `float`. Если точности `float` недостаточно, то ваш выбор невелик — `double`. Если у вас вообще нет никаких притязаний — выбирайте что угодно, разницы не увидите.

---

Я, как участник вышеозначенного спора, решил написать ответ. Для того, чтобы понять, какая будет производительность, я решил сначала изучить немного теории, для этого я написал следующий код:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
int main()
{
    volatile double darray[] = {5.234234, 2.2143213, 3.214212, 4.123155};
    volatile float farray[] = {5.234234f, 2.2143213f, 3.214212f, 4.123155f};

    volatile double dres = 0.0;
    volatile float fres = 0.0f;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        dres += darray[i];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        fres += farray[i];
    fres = 0.0;
}
```

Для которого мы имеем следующий ассемблер(gcc):

```cpp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-96]
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-64+rax*8]
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rbp-104]
        addsd   xmm1, xmm0
        movq    rax, xmm1
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-104], rax
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-96], 1
.L2:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-96], 3
        jbe     .L3
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-88], 0
        jmp     .L4
.L5:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-88]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-80+rax*4]
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rbp-108]
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movd    eax, xmm1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-108], eax
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-88], 1
.L4:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-88], 3
        jbe     .L5
```

Это не весь вывод, но тут достаточно информации. Для нас интересны тут две инструкции: `addss`, `addsd` — каждая является SIMD инструкция по работе с float(первая) и double. Первая мысль — надо поискать мануал, может там написано, что быстрее? Такой мануал [есть](http://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html), но беглый осмотр показал, что ответа я там не получу — судя по мануалу эти инструкции должны исполняться одинаково быстро. Хорошо. Оставим этот путь и попробуем собрать предыдущий код с AVX2 в студии, получим следующим asm:

```cpp
; 6    : 
; 7    :     volatile double dres = 0.0;
; 8    :     volatile float fres = 0.0f;
; 9    :     for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)

    xor eax, eax
    vxorps  xmm2, xmm2, xmm2
    vmovsd  QWORD PTR dres$[rsp], xmm0
    vmovss  DWORD PTR fres$[rsp], xmm2
    mov ecx, eax
    npad    9
$LL4@main:

; 10   :         dres += darray[i];

    vmovsd  xmm1, QWORD PTR darray$[rsp+rcx*8]
    vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR dres$[rsp]
    inc rcx
    vaddsd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    vmovsd  QWORD PTR dres$[rsp], xmm1
    cmp rcx, 4
    jb  SHORT $LL4@main
    npad    1
$LL7@main:

; 11   :     for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
; 12   :         fres += farray[i];

    vmovss  xmm1, DWORD PTR farray$[rsp+rax*4]
    vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR fres$[rsp]
    inc rax
    vaddss  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    vmovss  DWORD PTR fres$[rsp], xmm1
    cmp rax, 4
    jb  SHORT $LL7@main
```

Код практически не изменился, кроме того, что операции стали называться `vaddsd` и `vaddss`. Я не стал лезть в мануал по этим командам, полагаю что ситуация там схожа с теми, что мы видели ранее.

Тогда пойдём другим путём: мы знаем, что `float` является 32-х битным, тогда как double является 64-х битным. Это неминуемо должно сказаться на производительности, вопрос только один — как? Моё знание SIMD инструкций весьма ограничено, поэтому я не понимаю, почему ни gcc, ни студия не использовали какие-нибудь пакетные инструкции для сложения чисел. Кто нибудь может подсказать почему? Я уж было решил, что таких нет. Но вот [эта](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions) статья утверждает, что такие есть: `VADDPD` и `VADDPS`, обе принимают аргументы размеров в 256-бит, т.е. за раз такая операция может сложить 8 float'ов или 4 double'а. Это уже что-то — float по праву меньшего размера должен быть быстрее и мы нашли, что это на самом деле так.

Другим важным фактором, который может вывести float вперёд является его меньшее влияние на кэш: т.к. он в два раза меньше, то и нагрузка на кэш будет меньше. Таким образом, не распинаясь и не расписывая больше, получаем следующий вывод, который, в целом, сразу приходит в голову: `float` быстрее чем `double`.

Осталось проверить это на практике, для этого используем следующий код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const size_t size = 1'000'000'000;
    std::vector<double> dvector(size, 2.2143213);
    std::vector<float> fvector(size, 2.2143213f);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile double dres = std::accumulate(dvector.begin(), dvector.end(), 0.0);
    auto doubleElapsed = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile float fres = std::accumulate(fvector.begin(), fvector.end(), 0.0f);
    auto floatElapsed = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();

    std::cout << "float elapsed: " << floatElapsed << "\n";
    std::cout << "double elapsed: " << doubleElapsed << "\n";
    float ratio = std::max<float>(floatElapsed, doubleElapsed) /
        std::min<float>(floatElapsed, doubleElapsed);
    std::string relation = floatElapsed < doubleElapsed ?
        std::string("faster") : std::string("slower");
    std::cout << "float is " << ratio << " " << relation << "!\n";
}
```

На моём PC(Haswell) этот код, собранный в 2015 студии с AVX2, даёт стабильное преимущество `float` в 1.2-1.3 раза, бывают пиковые значения куда выше, но я не придавал им внимания. Даже без AVX2(я пробовал разные варианты) всё выглядит точно так же.

Разумеется, измерения довольно просты, а аргументация довольно поверхностная(я не ставил целью полноценное исследования, в настоящий момент у меня нет на него времени), но даже это показывает, что люди утверждающие, что нужно по умолчанию выбирать `double` и что `double` быстрее `float` — не правы.

---

И ещё один тест, где я использовал интринсики для подсчёта суммы(я может не лучшим образом их использовал, но уж как есть — по другому не умею):

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

float accumulate(const std::vector<float>& vec)
{
    __m256 res = _mm256_undefined_ps();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i += 8)
    {
        __m256 m1 = _mm256_load_ps(&vec[i]);
        res = _mm256_add_ps(m1, res);
    }
    float out[8];
    _mm256_store_ps(out, res);
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(out), std::end(out), 0.0f);
}

double accumulate(const std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    __m256d res = _mm256_undefined_pd();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i += 4)
    {
        __m256d m1 = _mm256_load_pd(&vec[i]);
        res = _mm256_add_pd(m1, res);
    }
    double out[4];
    _mm256_store_pd(out, res);
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(out), std::end(out), 0.0);
}

int main()
{
    const size_t size = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<double> dvector(size, 2.2143213);
    std::vector<float> fvector(size, 2.2143213f);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile double dres = accumulate(dvector);
    auto doubleElapsed = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile float fres = accumulate(fvector);
    auto floatElapsed = (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();

    std::cout << "float elapsed: " << floatElapsed << "\n";
    std::cout << "double elapsed: " << doubleElapsed << "\n";
    float ratio = std::max<float>(floatElapsed, doubleElapsed) /
        std::min<float>(floatElapsed, doubleElapsed);
    std::string relation = floatElapsed < doubleElapsed ?
        std::string("faster") : std::string("slower");
    std::cout << "float is " << ratio << " " << relation << "!\n";
}
```

С таким кодом, на той же машине, я получаю прирост в 2.3-2.5 раза.

Comment: Хороший ответ, однако возникает вопрос. Например, почему мы получаем прирост лишь x1.2-1.3, учитывая, что за операцию мы можем обработать 8 `float`ов и 4 `double`? По идее разница должна быть x2, однако мы ее не наблюдаем. Более того, мой тест на C#(тоже достаточно простой), показал разницу в производительности менее 1%, но тоже в пользу `float`, причем  сравнивалась производительность при простых операциях, т.е. не использовались функции, которые возвращают double. Эта разница наводит меня на мысль, что GCC использует не самые оптимальные инструкции  ради обеспечения кроссплатформенности.

Comment: "почему мы получаем прирост лишь x1.2-1.3, учитывая, что за операцию мы можем обработать 8 floatов и 4 double?" -- @МстиславПавлов, наверное, это уже ко мне вопрос, хотя @ixSci в принципе на него уже ответил. Посмотрите еще раз на `асм`. Тут в основном команды для работы с памятью. За пределами кеша это действительно медленные команды. По сути, вы сейчас посчитали не скорость сложения `float/double`-векторов, а скорость их загрузки в кеш. Я в своем ответе с кодом последний тест как раз делал с ошибкой, чтобы показать влияние кеша на результат.

Comment: @mega спасибо за пояснение.  Как я понимаю, если исключить вашу намеренную "ошибку", разница станет еще меньше, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: "если исключить вашу намеренную "ошибку", разница станет еще меньше, я правильно понимаю?" -- посчитайте сами: предпоследний результат - уже без ошибки. Мне просто @avp не сказал тогда своих характеристик для `RAM`, но показал, что его результаты лучше, поэтому я сделал последний "хитрый" тест. @ixSci может сделать такой же тест в своем последнем примере.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, добавил код с векторными инструкциями

Comment: @ixSci вот это уже серьезный аргумент. Постараюсь сегодня написать еще тесты на C#\Java, т.к. там разница в силу некоторых особенностей может быть существенной.

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Answer (score 6):

А что такое производительность в данном контексте? Вообще-то `SIMD` нам явно говорит о том, что в любой вектор вместится больше `float'ов`, поэтому **любые векторные операции над `float` будут всегда быстрее аналогичных - над `double`**, если опираться только на количественные характеристики алгоритмов.

Сравнивать тут нечего в таком контексте, например.

Если все же хотите сравнить, то можете взять код из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/306442/8766), изменив тип операндов на `double`/`float` соответственно (и команды с `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` на `_mm_cmpgt_pd/_mm_cmpgt_ps`). Замеры производительности там все есть.

Comment: Все же хотелось бы знать на сколько и в каких случаях. В частности все же интересно, какова разница в управляемых языках, таких как Java\C#. Т.к. в них поддержка SIMD инструкций относительно недавно, и поддерживается не полностью.

Comment: Опираясь на ту же архитектуру, можно сказать, что `float-операции` быстрее как минимум **в 2 раза**. Для примера: в `128-битном` векторном регистре умещается `2 double` или `4 float`. Почему минимум - потому что на подготовку векторов могут идти дополнительные издержки, которые будут оценены в том же соотношении. От выбранного языка тут мало что зависит, скорее - от компилятора, от его качества оптимизациионных алгоритмов под задействование `SSE`.

Comment: А вот простой тест показывает, что на обычных математических операциях(деление\умножение) флоат быстрее менее чем на 1%.

Comment: Разве сопроцессор не приведёт их к одному типу?

Comment: Разумеется, производительность, как и любое профилирование, зависит от того, что мы считаем типичным набором операций. Если наши операции — числомолотилка (повторяемые миллионы раз одинаковые вычисления над огромным количеством данных), то результат один. Если это что-то более интеллектуальное (да хоть расчёт координат по данным с GPS), результат другой. Размер линии кэша интересен только для числомолотилок.

Comment: @VladD, что Вы заладили про свои числомолотилки? Я Вам ещё раз говорю, посмотрите видео с конференций, гугла там, майкрософта. У них числомолотилки сплошные в софте, да?

Comment: @ixSci: Тяжесть доказательства того, что весь современный софт состоит из числомолотилок, лежит на утверждающем, то есть на вас. Я за свою практику с такого рода кодом сталкивался всего лишь один раз, и собственно критичная по скорости часть составляла ничтожную долю логики проекта. (А выигрыш по производительности достигался не за счёт задирания скорости перебора данных, а за счёт алгоритмики.)

Comment: @VladD, приехали, про числомолотилки начали как раз Вы. Я ничего такого не говорил, я говорил и говорю, что кэш влияет на все приложения, просто на одни меньше, а на другие больше. Те, что используют любые контейнеры подвержены влиянию кэша.

Comment: @ixSci: Вы утверждаете, что случаи, в которых эффект от длины линии кэша начинает сказываться, достаточно распространены, чтобы считать это «случаем по умолчанию». Это настолько противоречит всей моей практике, что я вынужден потребовать у вас обоснования.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрите [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs) видео.

Comment: @ixSci: Там больше часа, может, укажете, с какой минуты там обоснование нужного утверждения? (То, что гуглу где-то нужна числомолотилка, я как бы не сомневаюсь, я сомневаюсь в том, что она нужна другим.)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34472/discussion-between-ixsci-and-vladd).

Answer (score -4):

Так как вес float и double одинаков, скорость компиляции и работы будет только зависеть от количества чисел до и после запятой, моё мнение, я использую тип float

Comment: Что вы понимаете под словом «вес»?

Comment: @VladD вес компьютера не зависит от того, какие типы хранятся в памяти. Значит и вес типов `float` и `double` одинаков :)

Comment: вес - количество бит под тип

Comment: @Виктор, неправда. `float` и `double` соответствуют IEEE 754 binary32 (одинарная точность, всегда 4 байта) и binary64 (двойная точность, всегда 8 байт), так что различие в байтовой длине гарантируется стандартом.