# Чем структура отличается от класса?

Tags: c++, ооп

Так и все же, чем они отличаются? Если только спецификаторами доступа, то зачем для этого нужно было вводить класс?

Comment: тут скорее структуры были оставлены для обратной совместимости с Си-кодом.

Comment: В разделе 8.2.3. четвертого издания своей книги (не учебника) Страуструп пишет "A struct is simply a class where the members are public by default. So, a struct can have member functions (§2.3.2, Chapter 16)". Обратите внимание на  by defult поскольку есть возможность определять любые области доступа, как и в классах, определяемых ключевым словом class. Насчет мотивации я согласен с остальными: была необходимость оставить возможность использовать код C.

Comment: Иногда структуры полезны, чисто мое ИМХО

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Если только спецификаторами доступа, то зачем для этого нужно было вводить класс?

Ну так - именно для этого и нужно было. Было принято решение, что умолчательный доступ в классах в С++ должен быть уровня `private`. А менять умолчательный доступ в `struct` типах на `private` было бы чересчур серьезным изменением, убивающим на корню любую обратную совместимость с С. В те времена такая обратная совместимость была важна.

Больше отличий нет. Вы имеет право ссылаться на класс, ранее объявленный с ключевым словом `struct`, через ключевое слово `class` (и наоборот)

```
struct S;

class S
{
  ...
};
```

в также свободно использовать ключевые слова `struct` и `class` в elaborated type specifier независимо от того, как с каким словом класс был объявлен.

Comment: На это можно возразить, что кому нужно - может использовать `private` :) А вообще, искать какие-то **современные** обоснования, почему **когда-то** было сделано так, а не иначе - это все равно как http://boroda-30.livejournal.com/405214.html :)

Comment: @Harry: А почему вы это называете "современными" обоснованиями? У меня под рукой сейчас нет D&E, но по моему там именно это и написано. Да и "искать современные" не надо - я прекрасно владею оригинальными обоснованиями. Эти обоснования - не военная тайна. История языков С и С++ достаточно хорошо документирована.

Answer (score 2):

Лично я думаю, что это наследие Страуструпова "C с объектами" :)

В конце-концов, все, что можно сделать с `float`, можно делать и с `double` - но в языке остались и тот, и другой тип :)

Но с другой стороны, достаточно логично - наличие `struct` для простого агрегирования данных, и `class` для выражения объектов с поведением. Чисто для логического разделения этих сущностей. Тех, кто использует `struct` для классов, надо бить по пальцам так же, как и тех, кто использует `class` для простой структуры...

Но это не более чем мое мнение.

Comment: Но double ведь, условно говоря, тормозит в два раза больше, не?

Comment: Вообще говоря, например, в книге "Optimized C++" как раз указывается, что на современных процессорах `double` быстрее `float`...

Comment: @andreymal, места он занимает в два раза больше. Поэтому в массивах (особенно больших) предпочтительнее использовать `float`.

Comment: @Arhad При современной памяти это критично? Ну ладно, зачем тогда `int` и `long`, если это для большинства компиляторов одно и то же? И к чему еще куча всяких типов вроде `size_t`, `streamsize`, `ptrdiff_t` и иже с ними? А еще и наличие `typedef` и `using`...

Comment: @andreymal, вроде как сейчас поддерживается векторизация + хоть double, хоть int могут просчитаться за 1 такт. Как повезет с конвеером

Comment: С `float` и `double` аналогия не подходит, сегодня между ними есть [существенная разница при векторизации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483609/8766). Используется, соответственно, тот или иной тип в зависимости от потребностей поставленной задачи.

Comment: @Harry, критичен не сам объём (особенно на x64 архитектуре), а скорость его копирования с помощью того же `memcpy`. Согласен, на мелких массивах разницы никакой, но если массив большой, либо часто копируемый, разница может быть значительной.

Comment: @Harry: "...зачем тогда int и long, если это для большинства компиляторов одно и то же". Вообще-то `long` и `int` совпадают пожалуй только в MSVC. В gcc и clang `long` обычно больше `int`. Там совпадает как раз `long` и `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Повторю частично 1 ответ:
У `struct` все поля по умолчанию `public` и при наследование по умолчанию `public`, у `class` — и то, и другое `private`.