# Почему происходит переполнение и как избавиться от него

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml

Задание: Написать программу "Пульсирующий шар". Пульсации происходят со скоростью MAX_RISING = 2 * 15.f / сек.

Я заметил что происходит переполнение в строке:
const float currRisingPerFrame = std::abs((MAX_SIZE - curr_ball.getRadius()) / FRAME_DIVIDER * deltaTime), но не знаю как избавиться от него.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
constexpr float MAX_SIZE = 100.f;
constexpr float MIN_SIZE = 30.f;
constexpr float MAX_RISING = 15.f;
constexpr float FRAME_DIVIDER = 100.f;
const std::string WINDOW_TITLE = "Pumping ball";

void init(sf::CircleShape&, bool&, bool&);
void redrawFrame(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::CircleShape&);
void pollEvents(sf::RenderWindow&);
void update(float, sf::CircleShape&, bool&, bool&);

int main()
{
    sf::Clock clock;

    //Создаем окно с параметрами сглаживания
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT}), WINDOW_TITLE, sf::Style::Default, settings);

    //Объявляем фигуру
    sf::CircleShape curr_ball;

    bool isIncrease;
    bool isDecrease;

    init(curr_ball, isIncrease, isDecrease);

    //Выполняем основной цикл программы
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float deltaTime = clock.restart().asMilliseconds();
        pollEvents(window);
        update(deltaTime, curr_ball, isIncrease, isDecrease);
        redrawFrame(window, curr_ball);
    }
}

//Инициализируем фигуру-указатель
void init(sf::CircleShape& curr_ball, bool& isIncrease, bool& isDecrease)
{
    //Устанавливаем радиус шара
    curr_ball.setRadius(MIN_SIZE);
    //Устанавливаем координаты центра шара
    curr_ball.setPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2);
    //Устанавливаем цвет шара
    curr_ball.setFillColor(sf::Color(0xFF, 0x9, 0x80));
    //Устанавливаем значения переменных рост/уменьшение шара
    isIncrease = true;
    isDecrease = false;
}

//Рисует и  выводит один кадр
void redrawFrame(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::CircleShape& curr_ball)
{
    window.clear();
    window.draw(curr_ball);
    window.display();       
}

//Опрашивает и обрабатывает доступные события в цикле
void pollEvents(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    sf::Event event{};
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            default:
                break;        
        }
    }
} 

void update(float deltaTime, sf::CircleShape& curr_ball, bool& isIncrease, bool& isDecrease)
{
    //Вычисляем смещение и задаем пульсации шара
    const float maxRisingPerFrame = MAX_RISING/ FRAME_DIVIDER * deltaTime;
    const float currRisingPerFrame = std::abs((MAX_SIZE - curr_ball.getRadius()) / FRAME_DIVIDER * deltaTime);

    std::cout << "deltaTime == " << deltaTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "maxRisingPerFrame == " << maxRisingPerFrame << std::endl;
    std::cout << "currRisingPerFrame == " << currRisingPerFrame << std::endl;
    std::cout << "isIncrease == " << isIncrease << std::endl;
    std::cout << "isDecrease == " << isDecrease << std::endl;
    std::cout << "curr_ball Radius == " << curr_ball.getRadius() << std::endl;

    if ((curr_ball.getRadius() < MAX_SIZE) && (isIncrease == true))
    {
        curr_ball.setRadius(curr_ball.getRadius() + std::min(maxRisingPerFrame, currRisingPerFrame));
        if (curr_ball.getRadius() == MAX_SIZE)
        {
            isIncrease = false;
            isDecrease = true;        
        }    
    }
    else if ((curr_ball.getRadius() > MIN_SIZE) && (isDecrease == true))
    {
        curr_ball.setRadius(curr_ball.getRadius() - std::min(maxRisingPerFrame, currRisingPerFrame));
        if (curr_ball.getRadius() == MIN_SIZE)
        {
            isIncrease = true;
            isDecrease = false;        
        }
    } 
}
```

Здесь можно увидеть когда происходит переполнение переменной currRisingPerFrame:

```
maxRisingPerFrame == 0.15
currRisingPerFrame == 0.000102081
isIncrease == 1
isDecrease == 0
curr_ball Radius == 99.9898
deltaTime == 1

maxRisingPerFrame == 0.15
currRisingPerFrame == 0.000101089
isIncrease == 1
isDecrease == 0
curr_ball Radius == 99.9899
deltaTime == 1

maxRisingPerFrame == 0.15
currRisingPerFrame == 0.000100098
isIncrease == 1
isDecrease == 0
curr_ball Radius == 99.99
deltaTime == 1

maxRisingPerFrame == 0.15
currRisingPerFrame == 9.91058e-005
isIncrease == 1
isDecrease == 0
curr_ball Radius == 99.9901
deltaTime == 1

maxRisingPerFrame == 0.15
currRisingPerFrame == 9.8114e-005
isIncrease == 1
isDecrease == 0
curr_ball Radius == 99.9902
deltaTime == 1
```

Comment: Не по сути вопроса - копаться сейчас некогда - но почему так старательно используют `float`, а не `double`? При нынешнем состоянии дел смешно говорить как об экономии памяти, так и о повышении эффективности вычислений (кстати, Гантерот в "Оптимизации программ на С++" утверждает, что `double` обычно как раз быстрее).

Comment: В каком именно месте происходит переполнение? В последнем примере: `(100.f - 99.9902) / 100.f * 1 ≈ 9.8114e-005`. Что не так?

Comment: Мой миелофон подсказывает, что ТС не вполне знаком с экспоненциальной записью, и считает результат каким-то большим значением. Например, 9.91.

Comment: @Harry Графические API, вроде OpenGL и, в данном случае, SFML, часто используют `float` для представления координат в массовых геометрических данных. Учитывая массовость данных, там это вполне уместно. Что касается того, какой тип данных в такой ситуации следует использовать для локальных вычислений... интересный вопрос.

Comment: @AnT, [Float vs Double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483591/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-float-vs-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О каком переполнении идет речь?

9.91058e-005 - это 0.0000991058
Разница между ним и 0.000100098 равна 0.000000993.
Для сравнения, разница между 0.000101089 и 0.000100098 равна 0.000000991.

Ознакомьтесь с [экспоненциальной записью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)